# Run a project using sublime text editor 3

Tags: angularjs, sublimetext

I'm very new to angularJS and sublime text editor. I have downloaded a sample project from GitHub and trying to open using sublime text editor 3. when I was trying to run the project it is not showing any thing. Do I need any plugins?
As in java, we try to download a project and import it. In the same way, how can I run an angular project using sublime text editor 3?

Comment: sublime is the text editor.. it doesnt have much facility like eclipse for java and all. but you can do i think.. which server are you using?

Comment: Instead of sublime better use visual studio code

Comment: Please make sure whenever you put tags about Angular then make sure if you want it for Angular1.x then you need to use `angularjs` and for Angular2/4 use `angular` tags.

Comment: It is not clear, what is a configuration of your project, did you included angular itself, do you use node.js and so on. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime is a text editor. You can't run an AngularJS project through a text editor. For doing that, you'll require an IDE. What you are referring to downloading and importing a java based project, you actually are referring to an IDE like Eclipse,IntelliJ IDEA, etc.

Look up for IDEs that you can use for your AngularJS projects.

Answer (score 0):

**sublime** is the text editor.. it doesnt Run server facility like eclipse for java and all. as per your requirement you need IDE like `Eclipse`, `Visual Studio code` kind of..

but still you can highlight angularJS syntax in sublime editor. for syntax highlight, press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` in that section you can search and install angularjs package.. it will highlight you code. as well, it will suggest available syntax based on your code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add plugins to your Sublime to access syntax checking, code highlighting and code build features.

Basically you need to install **two** plugins :

1. [TypeScript Plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TypeScript)
2. [Angular CLI Plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Angular%20CLI)

Usage and installation guide is present in the above mentioned links.